# Translate "5 times as many" in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a city there are 5 times as many tourists as locals.
What can I say regarding it in percentage or in probability terms beside if locals are x then tourists are 5x? Could we get a concrete percentage of how locals and tourists are distributed in the city?

Comment: If there are $x$ locals and $5x$ tourists, then there are $6x$ people in total, and  $\frac 16$ of them are local.

Comment: If you don't need a percentage or fraction, this is very easily expressed as *odds* rather than probability, with no math required - with 5x as many tourists as locals, the odds of a random person being a tourist is 5:1.

Comment: this has nothing to do with probability. (I'm referring to what you actually wrote above, not to whatever you had in mind...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everyone is either a tourist or a local, then we know that the total proportions of both groups add to 1. So we have $x + 5x = 1$, where $x$ is the proportion of locals. Clearly $x=\frac{1}{6}$, and the proportion of tourists is $5x = \frac{5}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let,
x+5x= total no. of tourist
6x=100%
x=100/6=16.6%

Comment: Please learn mathjax to present your answers in a better manner. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference